# Keep an element at bottom of div while keeping it in the flow

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

I am looking to keep an element at the bottom of a sidebar. To achieve that, one of the easiest solution would be:

```
  #container
  {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
  }

  #bottom-element
  {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    bottom: 0;
  }
```

The result of this code is going to be:

[image]

However, I also need to keep the sidebar responsive. And since an `absolute position` removes the `#bottom-element` from the flow, if the sidebar's height becomes too small, the `#bottom-element` is going to cover the blue elements, instead of creating a scrollbar.

So my question is:
**How to keep the red element at the bottom of the sidebar, while keeping it at the bottom of the blue elements list when the sidebar is not tall enough?**

Comment: Is the element last in the source order?

Answer (score 3):

Just add some bottom padding to the container equal to the height of the absolutely positioned element:

```
 #container
  {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  #bottom-element
  {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    bottom: 0;
  }
```

**Update** you might also want to add `box-sizing: border-box` to stop the padding being added to the 100% height. I've updated the CSS with this.